# RESTful cross authentication

Tags: rest, oauth, java-ee-6, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I have 2 RESTful services realized in JAX-RS (Jersey): "A" and "B". They are deployed on a separate application servers. "A" and "B" are both of mine.

1. Client connect and login at "A" service;
2. Client ask "A" for resource, for example: https://blabla1/services/myresources;
3. For retrieve resource "myresources" service "A" should ask (not redirect) service "B" for another resource, for example: https://blabla2/services/anotherresources.

Service "B" need authenticate too, that's the problem. Is it possible, that service "A" ask "B" with client authentication parameters, and how it will works ?

I guess it's possible with oauth library, but I can't find any examples (close to my problem) and howto's.

Thanks

Comment: If you own both service "A" and service "B" then can you just have a private RESTful Service that allows "A" to call "B" without the authentication needed?

Since "A" did the authentication, you should be fine from a user security perspective. And you can secure the private service to ensure no one else can call it.

Comment: How I can secure the private service to ensure no one else can call it ?

Comment: Digital certificate that's only known to the "A" and "B" services is what I usually use.

Do you have an internal network that "A" and "B" can both access, but isn't open to the outside world? If so, you can block the service from any external network.

Comment: No, "A" and "B" are connecting via Internet only

Comment: Then I would go with a call to B that is rejected without the correct digital certificate.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, Mark S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing the solution outlined in the comments:

Service "B" (or a proxy in front of it) should only accept HTTPS requests with the certificate of server "A". (Server "A" can also validate server "B"'s certificate to avoid man in the middle attacks.)

Then the user name can be a plain text request parameter.

If you have better networking people than server people or find SSL daunting, have the network people establish a secure tunnel (forming a VPN) between your sites instead, and make service "B" unavailable from the raw Internet besides the tunnel.

Comment: Also consider adding firewall rules on both sides to secure the channel _in addition to_ the SSL. No sense in letting the outside world even know that there is a door there for them to try.